# JustDecompile / dotPeek show me an assembly's source code. How can I modify it?

Tags: .net, decompiling

I can see the original source code with the decompilers, but how do I modify the source code and re-compile the .DLL afterwards?

Answer (score 15):

First of all, you do not see the original source code; you see reverse-engineered source code.

If you are interested in programmatically modifying an assembly, have a look at these projects:
* The [**Common Compiler Infrastructure (CCI) Metadata**](http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/) and [CCI AST](http://cciast.codeplex.com/) projects on CodePlex. That's exactly what they are for.

> "*[CCI] allows applications to efficiently analyze or modify .NET assemblies, modules, and debugging (PDB) files."* — from the project's website

IIRC, CCI Metadata works at a fairly low level of abstraction. If you want to modify or insert code with it, you'll have to deal with Intermediate Language (IL). CCI AST provides higher-level abstractions (abstract syntax trees).

(Btw. I suppose CCI won't allow you to tamper with strongly-named (signed) assemblies, since that would defeat their purpose.)

- [**Mono.Cecil**](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil). It was developed for Mono, but works on .NET too:

  > *"In simple English, with Cecil, you can load existing managed assemblies, browse all the contained types, modify them on the fly and save back to the disk the modified assembly."* — from the project's website

Btw., there's a question here on Stack Overflow that asks for [a comparison of the two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727715/cci-vs-mono-cecil-advantages-and-disadvantages).

### **Other related libraries / frameworks:**

- [**Roslyn**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/roslyn). This project's focus is on the representation of source code as abstract syntax/parse trees, and allows you to do e.g. source code analysis and manipulation. It's also supposed to be able to compile source code for you. However, Roslyn is *not* specialized on assembly manipulation. (To summarise, you could think of Roslyn as a mix of System.CodeDom and System.Linq.Expressions, but much more powerful than either of these.)
- [Kevin Montrose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80572/kevin-montrose) has written an IL-emitting library called **[Sigil](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/sigil)** which is "A fail-fast, validating helper for DynamicMethod and ILGenerator."
- You can use the `ildasm` (IL disassembler) and `ilasm` (IL assembler) to do something called "round-tripping" (read about it e.g. [on Mike Stall's blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2006/01/13/debugabbility-with-roundtripping-assemblies/)):

  > Round-tripping is where you decompile an app (perhaps via ILDasm), potentially edit the IL, and then recompile it (perhaps via ILAsm). This is the backbone for rewriting an assembly [...].
- A last option is the [**System.Reflection**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.reflection.aspx) and [**System.Reflection.Emit**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.reflection.emit) functionality in the .NET Base Class Library (BCL). The former allows you to inspect assemblies. The latter provides functionality to generate & save new assemblies to disk. As with CCI, you'll have to deal with raw IL. Also, I don't think they allow you to modify an existing assembly easily.

Comment: So, when using those tools, I suppose to generate the source code first, and compile it with another tool? Or can I just insert new code with those tools?

Comment: I heard about this ILSpy 2.0 I can decompile the project to a Visual C# project, is that a good product? It does have type or namespace not found errors.

Comment: I don't know ILSpy, but why don't you give it a try yourself and see if it meets your requirements?

Answer (score 2):

A [plugin for JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler/extensions.aspx) allows you to edit assemblies. Go to the **Assembly Editor Plug-In** section.